# HOW to set_userdata login codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I get Message error: Trying to get property of non-object, and i dont know solved this problem. please help

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function login_user(){
     $user =array( 'email_user'=> $this->input->post('email_user'),
            'password_user'=> $this->input->post('password_user'));
     $myquery= $this->user_model->login_check($user['email_user'], 
             $user['password_user']);
 if ($myquery== TRUE) {
     foreach($myquery as $d){ 
         $session_array = array(
               'id_user'=>$d->id_user,
               'username_user'=>$d->username_user,
               'email_user'=>$d->email_user,
               'phone_user'=>$d->phone_user,
               'tanggal_lahir'=>$d->tanggal_lahir
         );
         $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn',$session_array);}
         $this->load->view('v_formluar.php');
      }
      else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Error occured,Try again.');
        $this->load->view('v_login.php');
      }
 }
```

I don't know to get data from model to controller,

**MY MODEL**

```
public function login_check($email, $password){

   $this->db->select('registrasi.user_id,
                      registrasi.username_user,
                      registrasi.email_user,
                      registrasi.password_user')
      ->from('registrasi')
      ->where("registrasi.email_user = '$email' OR registrasi.username_user = '$email' ");

     $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide proper error message with line number

Comment: With the above model query, Are you getting the record?

Answer (score 0):

Your use  of `$myquery` is not correct since your model return data or false. Change the controller code as follows:

```
 public function login_user(){
 $user =array( 'email_user'=> $this->input->post('email_user'),
        'password_user'=> $this->input->post('password_user'));
 $myquery= $this->user_model->login_check($user['email_user'], 
         $user['password_user']);
 if ($myquery!=FALSE) {
 foreach($myquery as $d){ 
     $session_array = array(
           'id_user'=>$d->id_user,
           'username_user'=>$d->username_user,
           'email_user'=>$d->email_user,
           'phone_user'=>$d->phone_user,
           'tanggal_lahir'=>$d->tanggal_lahir
     );
     $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn',$session_array);}
     $this->load->view('v_formluar.php');
  }
  else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Error occured,Try again.');
    $this->load->view('v_login.php');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you load the model in your controller:

```
$this->load->model('your_model_name_m');
```

Then you can use the model in your controller:

```
$logged_in = $this->your_model_name_m->login_check('me@us.com', 'password!#$');
```

If you frequently use this model, you can also autoload it via the config file in the model section:

```
$autoload['model'] = array( "your_model_name" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing

```
if($myquery==TRUE){ 
// your code
}
```

with

```
if($myquery){ 
// your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Model

Use brackets with your database condition

```
public function login_check($email, $password){
$this->db->select('registrasi.user_id,
                  registrasi.username_user,
                  registrasi.email_user,
                  registrasi.password_user')
  ->from('registrasi')
  ->where("(registrasi.email_user = '$email' OR registrasi.username_user = '$email' )");

 $query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() == 1){
    return $query->row();
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Your Controller

```
if(isset($myquery) && $myquery != ''){
    //foreach loop
}else{
 //No record found
}
```

You can also use `where()` and `or_where()` for your condition

[Read More](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=active%20records#selecting-data)